# PHP Read local .sq3 file for use on webpage

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a local file (tf2stats.sq3) stored on my web server that includes name and points of players like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF4bl.png

My intention is to get the top 10 entries for POINTS and display them on a webpage as a leaderboard.

I can't find any examples on reading a .sq3 database without first connecting to a server.

Here's one of them:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The problem is that the game server with the database does not have mySQL set up, so I planned on periodically downloading the file over FTP and reading it locally.

Right now I have the files stored on a directoy of my website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrwBy.png

I have php-mysql and php7.0-mysql packages installed on my web server which is using php7.0 - so far every attempt I've made to read the db gives me "No such file or directory"

I'm very new to php and sql, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I advice you to read this http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php (Native PHP) or this one http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php (PECL extension)

Comment: "I can't find any examples on reading a .sq3 database without first connecting to a server." SQLite does not have a server by the way it's just a file your mixing it wiith MySQL which does indeed uses a server client model.

Comment: Yep, you are mixing up sqlite with mysql.

Comment: Thanks, that's where I was making my error. I ended up basing my php program on this: http://henryranch.net/software/ease-into-sqlite-3-with-php-and-pdo/
and everything's working fine.